# Laravel error Trying to get property of non-object when filtering with relashionship

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting error `Trying to get property of non-object` when I try to get value of

```
{{ $user->adminProfile->company_name }}
```

Here *adminProfile* has relationship with *User* model. The relation is correctly defined.

When I use

```
$users = User::role('admin')->with('adminProfile')->get();
```

it works perfectly. However, I am getting the error when one more filter is used

```
$users = User::role('admin')->with(['adminProfile' => function($q) {
    $q->where('status', 1);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Is the status of the to the user related admin profile `1`?

Comment: yes. Its boolean, either 1 or 0.

Comment: u got a collection and want to get model value

Comment: Could you show us the relation?

Comment: ```return $this->hasOne(AdminProfile::class);``` and ```return $this->belongsTo(User::class);``` this is summary

Comment: Do you only want to display the users that have a `adminProfile` with `'status'  == 1`?

Comment: @Remul correct.

Comment: Are you sure that the admin profile has a status of `1`?

Comment: Yes. If I use ```User::with('AdminProfile')->where('status', 1)->get()``` it works fine.

Comment: That means you're checking for the status of the user and not the status of the admin profile?

Comment: Please show us your tables with the data.

Comment: Sorry, made mistake in previous comment. Actually I am getting proper value if I use ```User::role('admin')->with('adminProfile')->get();``` so relation is ok, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are getting **ALL** users with the role admin, but you are **ONLY** loading the `adminProfiles` with status 1.

This means that you will have users where the `adminProfile` relationship will return `null`.

In order to filter out the users that do not have a `adminProfile` with the status 1 you will have to use a [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) instead of a `with`:

```
$users = User::role('admin')->whereHas(['adminProfile' => function($q) {
    $q->where('status', 1);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I thinik I failed to explain. AdminProfile is also a model and has one2one relation with User model. I am using with for that relationship. Status is a column in AdminProfile model. Basically I am using 2 filters- by admin role and status; each from different tables

Comment: You only want to display the users that have the status == 1 on their `adminProfile` right?